# Using a ToggleButton with a while loop JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a JavaFX application that has a toggle button. I want a while loop to run as long as the button is toggled and stop when the button is toggled off. Right now in the program, the while loop activates when I press the button but the loop does not stop when I toggle off the button. Is there something I'm missing to make the loop stop when I toggle off the button?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    private BorderPane layout;
    private Scene scene;


    ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton("Button");
    AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        layout = new BorderPane();
        scene = new Scene(layout, 450, 80);



        button.setOnAction(e -> robot());

        layout.setCenter(button);


        window.setTitle("Desktop App");
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

    }

    public void robot() {


        Map<Integer, Character> keyMap = new HashMap();

        running.set(button.isSelected());

        keyMap.put(1, 'a');
        keyMap.put(2, 'b');
        keyMap.put(3, 'c');
        keyMap.put(4, 'd');
        keyMap.put(5, 'e');
        keyMap.put(6, 'f');
        keyMap.put(7, 'g');
        keyMap.put(8, 'h');
        keyMap.put(9, 'i');
        keyMap.put(10, 'j');
        keyMap.put(11, 'k');
        keyMap.put(12, 'l');
        keyMap.put(13, 'm');
        keyMap.put(14, 'n');
        keyMap.put(15, 'o');
        keyMap.put(16, 'p');
        keyMap.put(17, 'q');
        keyMap.put(18, 'r');
        keyMap.put(19, 's');
        keyMap.put(20, 't');
        keyMap.put(21, 'u');
        keyMap.put(22, 'v');
        keyMap.put(23, 'w');
        keyMap.put(24, 'x');
        keyMap.put(25, 'y');
        keyMap.put(26, 'z');
        keyMap.put(27, ' ');
        keyMap.put(28, '0');
        keyMap.put(29, '1');
        keyMap.put(30, '2');
        keyMap.put(31, '3');
        keyMap.put(32, '4');
        keyMap.put(33, '5');
        keyMap.put(34, '6');
        keyMap.put(35, '7');
        keyMap.put(36, '8');
        keyMap.put(37, '9');

        if(running.get()) {
            while(running.get()) //Only runs when the button has been toggled
            {
                int randomInt = (int )(Math.random() * 37 + 1);
                System.out.println(keyMap.get(randomInt));

            }
        }


            //while button is toggled
                //choose random integer
                //map the random integer to a key on keyboard
                //Robot presses key on focused window
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a *while* loop on the FX Application thread will block this thread, which means that no more interaction with the GUI is possible.

The condition of your *while* loop will never change, because of the `selectedProperty` of the `ToggleButton` will never change as the execution never exits the *while* loop.

You could use a [`Service`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) to execute the loop on a background thread to have the GUI responsive when the loop runs. `Service`s can be [canceled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#cancel--) and [restarted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#restart--).

**Example**

The following example creates a `Service` that runs a `Task` which executes a *while* loop until the `Service` gets cancelled.

I listen to the changes of the [`selectedProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html#selectedProperty--) of the `ToggleButton`:

- if selected: the service is reseted and started
- if not selected: the service gets cancelled

*Code*

```
ToggleButton toggle = new ToggleButton();

Service<Void> toggleService = new Service<Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {

        return new Task<Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                while(!isCancelled()) {
                    int randomInt = (int )(Math.random() * 37 + 1);
                    System.out.println(randomInt);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};

toggle.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if(newVal) {
        toggleService.reset();
        toggleService.start();
    }
    else 
        toggleService.cancel();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(button.isSelected()) {
            while(button.isSelected()) //Only runs when the button has been toggled
            {
                int randomInt = (int )(Math.random() * 37 + 1);
                System.out.println(keyMap.get(randomInt));

            }
        }
```

this should work

Comment: I just tried this and the button still wouldn't toggle off the while loop. This is a solution I previously had used before I looked and found the possible solution of using the AtomicBoolean, which also failed.

Comment: try to debug and see what is the value of `running.get()` using breakpoint on that line.

Comment: This blocks the JavaFX application thread and prevents any further interaction with the UI, including changing the `selected` state of the `ToggleButton`...